# How can I transform aesthetics 'on the fly' in ggplot using variables inside or outside the relevant dataframe?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, density-plot

In psychology, it's common to display histograms with an overlaying normal curve. Also showing the density of the observed values with geom_line would facilitate comparison to the normal curve, so I wrote another histogram function that does this (`powerHist` in the `userfriendlyscience` package). However, it performs very slowly for large vectors (currently working with 16.7 million datapoints), so I'm trying to make it faster. I used to use `density` to manually compute the density estimates, and then multiply them with maximum number of datapoints in a bin to scale it to match the histogram.

But this is very slow, plus, I figured ggplot2 should be able to do this. One of the variables computed by `stat_density` is `..scaled..`, which is the density estimate scaled to a max of 1. Now I just need to multiply this. But ggplot2 won't find the variable I use. Multiplying it with a constant works fine, but whether I place the variable in the dataframe I pass on to ggplot2 or not doesn't seem to matter: ggplot2 can't find it.

```
scalingFactor <- max(table(cut(mtcars$mpg, breaks=20)));
dat <- data.frame(mpg = mtcars$mpg,
                  scalingFactor = scalingFactor);
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=20) +
  geom_line(aes(y=..scaled.. * scalingFactor),
            stat='density', color='red');
```

This yields:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'scalingFactor' not found
```

When replacing the `scalingFactor` with a regular number, it works:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=20) +
  geom_line(aes(y=..scaled.. * 10),
            stat='density', color='red');
```

[image: Histogram with hardcoded scaled densitycurve]

Also, when just using `scalingFactor` on its own, it also works:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=20) +
  geom_line(aes(y=scalingFactor ),
            stat='density', color='red');
```

[image: Histogram with horizontal line showing scalingFactor]

So `scalingFactor` seems available; multiplication is available; and clearly `..scaled..` is available. Still, combining them seems to fail. What am I missing here? I can't find anything on 'computation with variables generated by stat' or something . . .

Has anybody run into this before? Is it known ggplot2 behavior that I just missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with `aes_q(y=bquote(..scaled.. * .(scalingFactor)))`

(although I would think there is a bug somewhere, since the environment argument in ?ggplot suggests this shouldn't be needed, and in fact isn't needed when dealing with variables that don't come from a stat)

Comment: Is there an issue for this in the ggplot2 github? The closest I could find is this https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2321 and while it seems related, I'm not certain if it's precisely the same thing.